# Using effects to make different size sticks around circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration, adobe-after-effects, effects

[image]I am beginner in Adobe illustrator. Which effects and shapes can I use to make these sticks around circle (Shown in red line in pic).

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking for an "effect", there isn't one.

There are of course methods to build such a design, such as creating one section of the design from rotated shapes, reflecting it, grouping the result, and rotating copies around a circle, and using a filled circle to hide pieces below.

For example

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am asking about first section to make group by rotating sticks, I am not able to make first bundle of sticks. I can apply reflect to make rest of the shape.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqarAmin There are tutorials online for rotating shapes around a circle. Basically you use the Rotate tool (R), hold down ALT, and click the centre of rotation, choose the number of degrees to rotate, hit Copy, and repeat using Ctrl+D the desired number of times.

Comment: Thank you very much for guiding. I get it now. I thought there might be some standard automatic way to make this, And i used answer field because there was no option to attach image in comment.